# How can I enable the permission within SetUp tab, to give access to an user to write a comment into a Case

Tags: customsetting, setup

I created a case and I want another user to be able to comment on it, but when he tries to do it a notification shows up saying that he does not have the permissions to do it. What is the permission within the SetUp tab to give him access to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_comments_edit.htm&type=5)

> To view case comments:    Read on cases
>
> To add case comments and make case comments public:   Edit or Create on cases
>
> To edit or delete case comments added by other users: Modify All on cases
>
> To edit, delete, or make public your existing case comments:  Edit Case Comments

You can use Permission Sets or Profiles to accomplish this